# Is there a specific way of retreiving only the required information from an HTML tree? Example included

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using python3.8 and BeautfiulSoup 4 to parse a website. The section I want to read is here:

```
<h1 class="pr-new-br">
     <a href="/rotring-x-b104743">Rotring</a>
     <span> 0.7 Imza Uçlu Kurşun Versatil Kalem 37.28.221.368 </span>
</h1>
```

I find this from the website using this code and get the text from it (soup is the variable for the BeautifulSoup object from the website):

```
product_name_text = soup.select("h1.pr_new_br")[0].get_text()
```

However, this ofcourse return me all of the text. I want to seperate the text between the `<a href>` and the text between `<span>.`

How can I do this? How can I specifically for for a tag or a link in a href?

Thank you very much in advance, I am pretty new in the field, sorry if this is very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get_text method has a parameter to split different elements' text.
As an example:

```
product_name_text = soup.select("h1.pr_new_br")[0].get_text('|')
# You will get -> Rotring|0.7 Imza Uçlu Kurşun Versatil Kalem 37.28.221.368
# Then you can split with same symbol and you would have list of different el's texts
```

Comment: Hey ExDet, just one more question. Is it possible to reach the web link inside <href>. Can't do that with the string method. How to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: @byetisener Yes, you should first find or select the 'a' element then use a['href'] it will give you that attribute's value ```a_href = soup.select("h1.pr-new-br a")[0]['href']```